# Setting text fields visiblity via a JButton

Tags: java, swing

So I have a really quick question. How can I set the visibility of text fields when a user presses an update button? I essentially want the text fields visibility set to false and when the user press a JButton, it sets the visibility to true. On the JButton, would I utilized an action event or a changed event? I have tried both and there seems to be no change in visibility. Below is my code and any input will be helpful. Thank you.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.plaf.PanelUI;

public class FirmLawyerProfile extends JDialog {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private final PrimaryLogin primaryLogin = new PrimaryLogin();
    private JTextField jtfLawyerFirstName;
    private JTextField jtfLawyerLastName;
    private JTextField jtfLawyerHomeAddress;
    private JTextField jtfLawyerPrimaryPhone;
    private JTextField jtfLawyerMiddleName;
    private JTextField jtfLawyerEmail;
    private JTextField jtfLawyerCity;
    private JTextField jtfLawyerZipCode;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FirmLawyerProfile dialog = new FirmLawyerProfile();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public FirmLawyerProfile() {
        setTitle("Firm Attorney Record");
        setBounds(100, 100, 998, 679);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPanel.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        panel.setBounds(0, 13, 200, 556);
        contentPanel.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel jlblFirmLawyerPicture = new JLabel("");
        jlblFirmLawyerPicture.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Justyn Bell\\Desktop\\abaApplicationImages\\blankProfile.jpg"));
        jlblFirmLawyerPicture.setBounds(41, 13, 115, 124);
        panel.add(jlblFirmLawyerPicture);

        JLabel jlblLawyerFirstName = new JLabel("[.getFirstName]");
        jlblLawyerFirstName.setBounds(12, 161, 95, 16);
        panel.add(jlblLawyerFirstName);

        JLabel jlblLawyerLastName = new JLabel("[.getLastName]");
        jlblLawyerLastName.setBounds(105, 161, 95, 16);
        panel.add(jlblLawyerLastName);

        JButton jbtnHome = new JButton("");
        jbtnHome.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                //this.FirmLawyerProfile.setVisible(false);
                FirmLawyerProfile.this.primaryLogin.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        jbtnHome.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Justyn Bell\\Desktop\\abaApplicationImages\\homeButton.jpg"));
        jbtnHome.setBounds(255, 497, 77, 72);
        contentPanel.add(jbtnHome);

        JButton jtbnRemove = new JButton("");
        jtbnRemove.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Justyn Bell\\Desktop\\abaApplicationImages\\removeButton.png"));
        jtbnRemove.setBounds(415, 497, 77, 72);
        contentPanel.add(jtbnRemove);

        final JButton jbtnUpdate = new JButton("");
        jbtnUpdate.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
                if(jbtnUpdate.isSelected()) {
                    jtfLawyerFirstName.setVisible(true);

                }
            }
        });


        jbtnUpdate.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\\\Desktop\\abaApplicationImages\\UpdateInformation.png"));
        jbtnUpdate.setBounds(569, 497, 77, 72);
        contentPanel.add(jbtnUpdate);

        JButton jbtnSave = new JButton("");
        jbtnSave.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\\\Desktop\\abaApplicationImages\\SaveButton.png"));
        jbtnSave.setBounds(743, 497, 77, 72);
        contentPanel.add(jbtnSave);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setLayout(null);
        panel_1.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Attorney Information"));
        panel_1.setBounds(212, 13, 734, 240);
        contentPanel.add(panel_1);

        JLabel jlblLawyerLegalSpeciality = new JLabel("Area of Legal Speciality");
        jlblLawyerLegalSpeciality.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        jlblLawyerLegalSpeciality.setBounds(312, 23, 134, 23);
        panel_1.add(jlblLawyerLegalSpeciality);

        JLabel jlblLawyerMiddleName = new JLabel("Middle Name");
        jlblLawyerMiddleName.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        jlblLawyerMiddleName.setBounds(342, 59, 80, 23);
        panel_1.add(jlblLawyerMiddleName);

        JLabel jlblEmail = new JLabel("Email");
        jlblEmail.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        jlblEmail.setBounds(342, 95, 68, 23);
        panel_1.add(jlblEmail);

        JLabel jlblLawyerCity = new JLabel("City");
        jlblLawyerCity.setBounds(342, 133, 80, 16);
        panel_1.add(jlblLawyerCity);

        JLabel jlblLawyerZipCode = new JLabel("Zip Code");
        jlblLawyerZipCode.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        jlblLawyerZipCode.setBounds(342, 162, 93, 23);
        panel_1.add(jlblLawyerZipCode);

        JLabel jlblLawyerDegreeInstitution = new JLabel("Degree Institution");
        jlblLawyerDegreeInstitution.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        jlblLawyerDegreeInstitution.setBounds(342, 198, 107, 23);
        panel_1.add(jlblLawyerDegreeInstitution);

        JLabel jlblLawyerPrefix = new JLabel("Prefix");
        jlblLawyerPrefix.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        jlblLawyerPrefix.setBounds(12, 23, 54, 23);
        panel_1.add(jlblLawyerPrefix);

        JLabel label_7 = new JLabel("First Name");
        label_7.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        label_7.setBounds(12, 59, 68, 23);
        panel_1.add(label_7);

        JLabel label_8 = new JLabel("Last Name");
        label_8.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        label_8.setBounds(12, 95, 68, 23);
        panel_1.add(label_8);

        JLabel label_9 = new JLabel("Home Address");
        label_9.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        label_9.setBounds(12, 130, 93, 23);
        panel_1.add(label_9);

        JLabel jlblLawyerStateOfResidence = new JLabel("State of Residence");
        jlblLawyerStateOfResidence.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        jlblLawyerStateOfResidence.setBounds(12, 162, 107, 23);
        panel_1.add(jlblLawyerStateOfResidence);

        JLabel jlblLawyerPrimaryPhone = new JLabel("Primary Phone");
        jlblLawyerPrimaryPhone.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        jlblLawyerPrimaryPhone.setBounds(12, 198, 107, 23);
        panel_1.add(jlblLawyerPrimaryPhone);

        JComboBox jcbLawyerSpeciality = new JComboBox(new Object[]{});
        jcbLawyerSpeciality.setBounds(458, 24, 228, 22);
        panel_1.add(jcbLawyerSpeciality);

        JComboBox jcbLawyerDegreeInstitution = new JComboBox(new Object[]{});
        jcbLawyerDegreeInstitution.setBounds(458, 198, 228, 22);
        panel_1.add(jcbLawyerDegreeInstitution);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(530, 198, 21, 22);
        panel_1.add(scrollPane);

        jtfLawyerFirstName = new JTextField();
        jtfLawyerFirstName.setColumns(10);
        jtfLawyerFirstName.setBounds(151, 59, 154, 22);
        panel_1.add(jtfLawyerFirstName);
        //jtfLawyerFirstName.setVisible(false); SHOULD I SET THIS SOMEHOW?

        jtfLawyerLastName = new JTextField();
        jtfLawyerLastName.setColumns(10);
        jtfLawyerLastName.setBounds(151, 95, 154, 22);
        panel_1.add(jtfLawyerLastName);

        jtfLawyerHomeAddress = new JTextField();
        jtfLawyerHomeAddress.setColumns(10);
        jtfLawyerHomeAddress.setBounds(151, 130, 154, 22);
        panel_1.add(jtfLawyerHomeAddress);

        JComboBox jcbLawyerStateOfResidence = new JComboBox(new Object[]{});
        jcbLawyerStateOfResidence.setBounds(151, 162, 80, 22);
        panel_1.add(jcbLawyerStateOfResidence);

        JComboBox jcbLawyerPrefix = new JComboBox(new Object[]{});
        jcbLawyerPrefix.setBounds(151, 23, 80, 22);
        panel_1.add(jcbLawyerPrefix);

        jtfLawyerPrimaryPhone = new JTextField();
        jtfLawyerPrimaryPhone.setColumns(10);
        jtfLawyerPrimaryPhone.setBounds(151, 198, 154, 22);
        panel_1.add(jtfLawyerPrimaryPhone);

        jtfLawyerMiddleName = new JTextField();
        jtfLawyerMiddleName.setColumns(10);
        jtfLawyerMiddleName.setBounds(458, 59, 154, 22);
        panel_1.add(jtfLawyerMiddleName);

        jtfLawyerEmail = new JTextField();
        jtfLawyerEmail.setColumns(10);
        jtfLawyerEmail.setBounds(458, 95, 154, 22);
        panel_1.add(jtfLawyerEmail);

        jtfLawyerCity = new JTextField();
        jtfLawyerCity.setColumns(10);
        jtfLawyerCity.setBounds(458, 130, 154, 22);
        panel_1.add(jtfLawyerCity);

        jtfLawyerZipCode = new JTextField();
        jtfLawyerZipCode.setColumns(10);
        jtfLawyerZipCode.setBounds(458, 162, 154, 22);
        panel_1.add(jtfLawyerZipCode);
        {
            JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
            buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
            getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried update the panel by calling `validate()` and then a `repaint()` on the `contentPanel`?

Comment: You need actionListener on jbutton

Comment: Also this part `if(jbtnUpdate.isSelected()) {
                    jtfLawyerFirstName.setVisible(true)`
only works with a toggle button

Comment: Learn to use LayoutManagers. Using a null layout and trying to set the component bounds at exact pixel locations will cause you great pain later, especially if you want to add something else, or you change fonts, or you try to run your program on a different machine

Comment: @bili, adding the validate and repaint() method to the content panel (contentPanel.validate();)worked fine I was attempting to put it just as vadiate(); I got it t work. Much obliged.

Comment: @Murk yay! You're welcome.